# Android app to block people for arbitrary time after I reject their call

Tags: android, phone

Some of my friends don't care when I reject their calls. They try and try again. Problem is - I have one number for private and business calls, so I cannot simply turn sound and vibration off. Might be, someone calls with a problem with my software and I have to answer, meeting or no.

Of course, if I knew I'm going to be at a meeting, I could add group "friends" to blacklist temporary, for an hour or two. But in the company I'm in, more common situation is that someone simply walks in and says "come on, you are needed", and I just get up and go. Or that few people come to my desk and start talking. So this is not an option. On the other hand, checking who is calling is perfectly appropriate.

Ideal solution would be - if someone calls and I reject his call, he should be automatically added to blacklist for two hours and I should not get any vibrations no matter how many times he writes or calls. Is there an Android app for that? Sounds simple, but I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: You can use tasker and take it a step further - [Answer the call and hangup  after a second](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/43120/119358)

Comment: @Manubhargav but the point is, these are people I like, and generally do want to talk with. All I need is temp block when I simply can not. Also, this still would require prior setup / turning on, something I can't do. Or it wouldn't and I'm missing something?